# Sheets header row ARRAYFORMULA to look up rate based on the job's turnaround AND date received within a range of dates

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I've got a Google Sheets workbook with two sheets:  [Jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIAT0.png)

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Turnaround** | **Received** | **Rate** | **Pages** | **Total** |
| **2** | Standard | 12/2/2021 | $0.40 | 204 | $81.60 |
| **3** | Rush | 12/9/2021 | $0.60 | 79 | $47.40 |
| **4** | Rush | 12/29/2021 | $0.60 | 24 | $14.40 |
| **5** | Standard | 1/1/2022 | $0.45 | 81 | $36.45 |
| **6** | Standard | 1/2/2022 | $0.45 | 137 | $61.65 |
| **7** | Standard | 1/5/2022 | $0.45 | 95 | $42.75 |
| **8** | Standard | 1/15/2022 | $0.45 | 162 | $72.90 |

[Rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ8vP.png)

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Turnaround** | **Base Rate** | **Start Date** | **End Date** |
| **2** | Standard | $0.40 | 9/1/2021 | 12/31/2021 |
| **3** | Rush | $0.60 | 8/17/2018 | 6/10/2022 |
| **4** | Expedited | $0.80 | 8/17/2018 | 6/10/2022 |
| **5** | Daily | $1.00 | 8/17/2018 | 6/10/2022 |
| **6** | Standard | $0.45 | 1/1/2022 | 6/10/2022 |

I'm trying to use an ARRAYFORMULA in Jobs!C1 to look up the value in Rates!B:B where the Turnaround in Jobs!A:A matches the Turnaround in Rates!A:A and the Date Received in Jobs!B:B falls on or between the Start Date in Rates!C:C and End Date in Rates!D:D.

The idea is that rates may change over time, but the job totals will still calculate using the correct rate at the time each job came in.

I know I can't use SUMIFS with ARRAYFORMULA, so I tried using QUERY, but this only populates the rate for the first job.

```
={"Rate"; 
ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(Rates!A:D, 
"select B where A contains '"&Jobs!A2:A
&"' and C < date'"&TEXT(Jobs!B2:B, "YYYY-MM-DD")
&"' and D > date'"&TEXT(Jobs!B2:B, "YYYY-MM-DD")&"'",0))}
```

I'm okay with adding helper columns if needed. I'm trying to avoid having to manually fill the formula down the column as jobs are added.

Here is a link to the workbook:
[Job Rate Lookup By Turnaround + Date Range](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WdU1eKUtG-Ylf-mj9nJRthsGDXZspJFWHvlFIIqOmB0/edit?usp=sharing)

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Is it necessary to have Standard twice? can the $0.45 price have a different name? I have already created a formula however I'm using Standard 2 as a name instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={"Rate"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B, SORT({
 FILTER(Rates!A2:A, Rates!A2:A<>"")&Rates!C2:C, Rates!B2:B}, Rates!C2:C, 1, Rates!A2:A, 1), 2, 1)))}
```

[image]

Comment: That isn't matching the Turnaround. The Rush jobs should be $0.60 and the Expedited should be $0.80, regardless of when they were received. Only the Standard should increase from $0.40 to $0.45 after 12/31/21.

Comment: @ncsushley answer updated. try now

Answer (score 0):

When using `ARRAYFORMULA` you won't be able to use `QUERY` in order to get the whole array of values as it will only return the first value that is found.

I created a formula that matches the value using `VLOOKUP` however I had to modify the name in `Jobs` from `Standard` to `Standard 2`.

This is the formula:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A,Rates!A2:D6,2,0)))
```

These are the results:

[image]